# Как переводится instantiation?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, терминология, локализация, перевод

Видел множество вариантов: инстанциация, инстанцирование, инстанцианирование  и т.п.. Есть ли какой-нибудь устоявшийся русский вариант?

Comment: Заходим в Гугл, запрашиваем... У меня только что выдало - инстанцирование - 12100 результатов, инстанциация - 1700, инстанцианирование - 2. Еще вопросы? :)

Comment: Яндекс Переводчик: Создание экземпляра.

Comment: @Harry почему это комментарий. а не ответ?:)

Comment: @Артур, потому что это не ответ,  Это совет  найти ответ  прогуглив, с намеком на правильное понимание этих слов

Comment: @ARHovsepyan так я гуглил и встретил разные варианты, которые привёл в вопросе. А по количеству результатов не сравнивал

Comment: Хорошо, написал ответ, который тянет на ответ, а не на комментарий :)

Comment: @Harry,  одним предложением ответили автору и намекнули мне? Круто!...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Да нет, с вами - совпадение, не более того... Просто действительно две строки на ответ не тянули.

Comment: Слова обычно используются  так, как вы их понимаете. Главное правильно понять значение этих слов и согласовать эти понятия с теми, с кем общаясь вы используете эти слова. Используя приведенные вами слова,   лично я говорил бы так:    "  Если инстанцирован шаблонный класс  Some_type , 
и инстанцианирован шаблон аргументом  'к',  то  практически  отдан команду компилятору создать класс   Some_type<k>. Если же инсанциация(процесс)  была успешной...." и т.д.

Comment: Вопрос бессмысленный. "Инстанциация, инстанцирование, инстанцианирование" чего? В каком контексте?

Такой термин фигурирует уже давно в ООП, где он обозначает одно.  Такой термин фигурирует "относительно недавно" в С++, где он обозначает другое. О чем идет речь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Заходим в Гугл, запрашиваем... У меня только что выдало - инстанцирование - 12100 результатов, инстанциация - 1700, инстанцианирование - 2. Еще вопросы? :)

Обычно, впрочем, такое считается не (только) голосованием в Интернете, но еще и (в первую очередь) "разумным, добрым, вечным" :) - книгами. Там в основном (не считая совсем уж левых издательств, которые просто бездумно "причесывают" текст машинного перевода) долго и тщательно думают над терминологией.

Возьму издательство, чьих книг у меня на полке больше всего - [Диалектика](http://www.dialektika.com/)/[Вильямс](http://www.williamspublishing.com/) - там сплошное инстанцирование - в применении к шаблонам С++.

И это логично, потому что "создание экземпляра" - это не совсем то, так как включает в себя и создание экземпляра обычного класса.

Ну, а уж из приведенных вами вариантов "инстанцирование" - самый благозвучный :)

P.S. На Интернет я бы не слишком полагался... недавно попался мне на глаза отзыв на сайте уж точно не помню где - мол, где вы берете кретинов-переводчиков? Что за "конструктор по умолчанию", когда давно и прочно принято говорить "дефолтный конструктор"? еще, кажется, он был недоволен "связыванием" - если есть "прибиндить" или как-то так... :)

Comment: Способ совершенно бесполезный. Никакого голосования в этом нет, не книгами, ни чем либо еще. Термин имеет несколько независимых и несвязанных значений в разных контекстах: есть классическое ООП инстанцирование ("создание экземпляра объекта"), есть специфично С++ инстанцирование шаблона ("материализация конкретной версии определения"). И поиск по гуглу лишь покажет относительную частоту упоминания этих контекстов. Нет никаких поводов полагать, что в разных контекстах этот термин должен переводится одинаково. Это не говоря о том, что в каждом контексте у термина могут быть свои синонимы.

Comment: @AnT Было бы интересно услышать вашу версию того, как создается, распространяется и принимается русскоязычная терминология, пусть хотя бы только в области программирования. Почему, например, шаблоны С++, а не темплейты? :)

Comment: Это интересная тема, но я что-то не вижу никакой связи с темой вопроса, не говоря уже о том, с чего бы вдруг у меня должна быть какая-то "версия". Я лишь констатирую сухой математический факт. Никаких "версий" не нужно.

Comment: @AnT Мне все же интересно узнать. Вы отметаете как источник устоявшийся в сообществе термин (а именно на это был направлен поиск в Гугле - на поиск термина de facto), точно так же отметаете книги (в определенном смысле терминология de jure). Что остается в качестве источника? Какие-то огненные письмена на мониторах русскоязычных пользователей? :) Если никаких версий не нужно - то откуда берутся термины? Которые, заметим, сплошь и рядом не совпадают ни со словарями, ни с жаргоном... Кстати, concepts в C++20 - пока  термин не устоялся. Как он будет устаканиваться до состояния "версий не нужно"?

Comment: Не надо заниматься дешевой демагогией. Я ничего не "отметал" и всем это прекрасно понятно. Я лишь заметил, что никакого отношения к "поиску устоявшихся терминов" или "книгам" ваши изыскания в гугле не имеют вообще, кроме разве что юмористического. Вы нашли какой-то ворох совпадающих по написанию слов из совершенно никак не связанных друг с другом контекстов и начали делать из этого какие-то выводы? Это профанация почище пресловутой "средней температуры по больнице"

Comment: @AnT, почему же вы уверены в своей правоте? И Не нужно грубить, особенно тогда, когда вас никто ничем не задел...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Вы о чем вообще? О каком "грубить"? Я констатировал очевидный факт, причем детально описал, о чем именно я веду речь. Никакого отношения ни ко мне, ни к моей "правоте" или "не правоте" этот факт не имеет.

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет о программировании, то можно использовать "Создание экземпляра".

Comment: нет, это не то конечно

Comment: И чем тогда это будет отличаться от создание экземпляра класса в ООП?

Comment: Речь про template instantiation

Comment: Применительно к шаблону, также встречается "материализация" и "кокретизация".

Comment: @Chorkov Материализацию можно спутать с temporary materialization.

Comment: @Chorkov *"Материализация духов и раздача слонов" (с)* Материализация - это уже явный перебор, а конкретизация - скорее получение конкретного класса на основе абстрактного...

Comment: @Артур: "Речь про template instantiation" - почему эта и информация отсутствует в вопросе? С момента вашего комментария прошел час и вы до сих пор не удосужились исправить вопрос. В чем заминка?